# How to detect single quotes in ANTLR4

Tags: parsing, antlr4

In an input file I have `'6'`, I'm trying to write some grammar that returns this as a `Char_num`

```
fragment Delim: ' ' | '\t' | '\n';

fragment Any_Char: .;

fragment Digit: [0-9];

WhiteSpace: Delim+ -> skip;

SemiColon: ';';

Char_Num: '\''Digit'\''; //This is the rule I'm trying to get work
```

This clearly doesn't work because running grun on this results in

```
line 1:0 token recognition error at: '''
line 1:2 token recognition error at: '''
```

I understand the error, but I'm not sure why it's wrong.

Comment: When I run your grammar as-is, I get an error because of the missing grammar-declaration at the beginning. If I add `token grammar bla;` as the first line, it compiles fine and accepts the input `'6'` as `Char_Num` without any problems. So it looks like you fixed your problem while trying to create a minimal example.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I had `lexer grammar bla`, but this was not the issue. I updated to the latest ANTLR version (4.7.1) and everything worked out fine.

Answer (score 0):

Updating ANTLR to the latest version (4.7.1 as of this writing) fixed it for me. Was on 4.5.3 before.